# Math in MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, math

I'm a complete novice but I really need to get this done as soon as possible so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a table with the following fields:
**userid**, **upvoteds** , **downvoteds**, **aposts** and **aselecteds**

Basically I need to run this formula for every row:

(**upvoteds** - **downvoteds**) / (**aposts** - **aselecteds**)
Apologies if that formula isn't structured properly.

I need the results presented in desc order along with **userid** so I know who it belongs to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select userid,
(upvoteds - downvoteds) / (aposts - aselecteds) as result
from table    
order by result desc
```